# Split number into n numbers

Tags: python, probability, distribution

Let's say I have a number **m** (it will be integer, usually 1) and I want to split **m** into **n** random numbers, which have the sum **m**. I want to make a distribution which will be random, but will be close (doesn't have to be really close) to uniform distribution.
I have this

```
pieces = []
for i in range(n-1):
    pieces.append(random.uniform(0,m-sum(pieces)))
pieces.append(m-sum(pieces))
```

The problem is, that the first number is usually really high compared to the rest of the numbers. When I tried it for **m = 1** and let's say **n=10**, the first number was close to **0,5** and the last number was close to like **0,001** (or something like that), which is not a problem, but the problem is, that the first number is on average really big compared to all of the other numbers.

My question is: Is there some kind of way to do this, so the numbers are closer? There can be a big difference between biggest and smallest number, but I want it to feel more uniform, if that makes sense.

Comment: You could try generating bins of equal size and then drawing numbers from bins in a manner to approximate a normal distribution

Comment: Or you can just shuffle the results after generating them, if you only care about position, not magnitude.